# An app designed for ios sdk 6, I can test it on an iPad1?

Tags: ios5, testing, ios6

In my app everything works, if I change the "Deployment Target" to 5.1 change anything? I have to remove all the autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES you have to remove autolayout and ios 6 specific api calls as well

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to samfisher's answer, you have to go inside each .xib file, then go to the right utilities bar, and the first tab (file inspector), and then uncheck the "Use autolayout".